# Google Recaptcha V3 CSP error Access to fetch at 'https://ssl.gstatic.com'

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, content-security-policy, recaptcha-v3

I'm using Recaptcha v3 and I've followed the directives to add to the CSP

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
script-src https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/;
frame-src https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/;
 ">
```

as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#im-using-content-security-policy-csp-on-my-website.-how-can-i-configure-it-to-work-with-recaptcha)

But I'm getting

```
 Access to fetch at 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/finance/favicon/finance_v2_180x180.png' from origin 'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Then

```
 m=base:587                  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at Kc.j (m=base:587:9)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is coming from the captcha script itself? I can't see what purpose the image returned by https://ssl.gstatic.com/finance/favicon/finance_v2_180x180.png should serve in that context to begin with.

Comment: Yes, If I remove <script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=xxx" defer></script> it goes away.  I believe this is the images for the recaptcha popup at the bottom of the page that you can hide. (it's hidden).

Comment: And without any CSP, same result, or does it work then?

Comment: Yes, it's adding the CSP as per the documentation that's the issue.